# How to model a pure join table with 2 primary keys to another pure join table with 3 primary keys in Entity Framework code first

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-relationship

How do I model a relationship where there is a pure join to another pure join table with three primary keys using code first?

Example code:

```
public class ItemA
{
    public int ItemAId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemB> ItemBs { get; set; }
}


public class ItemB
{
    public int ItemBId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemA> ItemAs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemC> ItemCs { get; set; }
}

public class ItemC
{
    public int ItemCId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemB> ItemBs { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ItemA> ItemA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemB> ItemB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemC> ItemC { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

EF creates a join table for (`ItemC` and `ItemB`) and another join table for (`ItemB` and `ItemA`) and I want to join (create a relationship) to another join table which has something like (`ItemA`, `ItemB`, `ItemC`) together, i.e., link `ItemA`, `ItemB`, and `ItemC` together.

How do you create a relationship/mapping join to another table with three primary keys (`ItemA`, `Itemb`, `ItemC`)?

Also, is this table really an entity that needs a class of its own so that Entity Framework can create this third table? (I wanted to avoid creating classes for things that only have primary keys in them, e.g., creating a class called `ItemAItemBItemC` that only has primary keys.)

Comment: Does that mean that you want a FK relationship between - for example - join table A-B and this table with the 3 PKs? If so, you even need to expose the A-B table as an entity in your model, not only the 3-PK table, because the A-B table would be more than just a join between A and B.

Comment: Yes I have already done that by creating a ItemCItemB class and adding an ICollection<ItemCItemB> to class ItemC (removing ICollection<ItemB> from ItemC,I thought with EF join relationships should not have classes because you would have a class with only primary keys and it would look strange to work with.